# missing permissions when using parent_id to get orignal post data Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

When sending request using  parent_id of a shared post to get original post i am getting status code 400 if the post shared are from other pages but works fine with self shares. Is the problem with my access token, if so how can i resolve it.

I am using the following api call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/<parent_id>/?fields=from&access_token=token
```

This gets the page_id ,name and post_id as they are my required information
This only works if the page is sharing its own posts otherwise following response:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Missing permissions",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AEVxnYgIlQq8Dck1n8TFgK3"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access) feature approved for your app, to be able to read posts by pages you don't have admin access to.

Only you are probably rather unlikely to get it approved, unless your use case matches the single allowed usage they mention there:

> Allowed Usage
>
> - Provide competitive benchmark analysis.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any alternative way to get the desired information of the original poster?

Comment: No official way via the APIs, no. So unless you want to resort to scraping (which Facebook makes difficult to begin with), this won't be possible - unless your use case _was_ any sort of "competitive benchmark analysis". What do you actually need this for?

Comment: Primary objective is to get data from pages and display the analysis using the  data on the front end

Comment: If "the analysis" means anything that could actually be considered to fall under "competitive benchmark analysis", then you can try and get this feature approved.

Comment: hope it does get approved